# Enemies need to move towards image

Tags: javascript, canvas

So basically I am creating a game where the player has to protect an object from colliding with enemies. However, I have tried looking at multiple tutorials online and none of them make no sense to me.

I am fairly new to coding and this is one of the essentials that I need for my game.

I know that you must use angles and constantly change the x and y values of the enemy by SetTimeout function, however I don't know where to start.

ANY HELP WOULD BE USEFUL!

Comment: It seems you need an example project to help you start from scratch.

Comment: I already  have code, just that I have nothing added to it (enemies following) so it seemed unnecessary to add it

Comment: I would look at using p5js if I was you. It is a javascript library which was built with beginners in mind. It allows you to do a lot of the things you would need to do with the canvas easily, such as getting user input, running a game loop etc... I would recommend looking at the YouTube channel The Coding Train to help you get started with p5js

Comment: I just want to know how to get an image (enemy) to follow another still image (player)

Comment: *"none of them make sense to me"* - how are we supposed to solve that problem? nothing makes sense the first time around. that's why not everyone is a programmer. watch, try, fail, repeat, learn, succeed.

Comment: because most of them follow them advanced tutorials with .json files etc. All I want to know is the basics of getting one image to follow another through canvas. There is no defined problem, just asking for a bit of guidance.

Comment: @johnandrews oh I see. Any enemy can either move up, down, left or right. For your enemies AI you can perform a check to see which movement of the enemy (up, down, left or right) moves the enemy closer to the player. Then make the enemy perform that movement. To check which movement moves the enemy closer to the player you'll need to calculate the distance between the player and the enemy

Comment: @johnandrews here is a very basic example. try recreating this and you will begin to learn how collision detection works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection